# GPU volatility in keras very low

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a multi-label image classification problem, this is mostly the entire code

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    """Generates data for Keras."""
    def __init__(self,csv_path ,batch_size=32, dim=(224, 224), n_channels=3,
                 n_classes=8, shuffle=True):
        self.img_files = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
        self.labels = self.img_files.iloc[:, 7:16].values
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.dim = dim
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        """Denotes the number of batches per epoch."""
        return int(np.floor(len(self.img_files) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        img_files_temp = [self.img_files['Left-Fundus'][k] for k in indexes]

        X, y = self.__data_generation(img_files_temp)
        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        """Updates indexes after each epoch."""
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.img_files))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, img_files_temp):
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size,self.dim[0], self.dim[1], self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.n_classes))
        for i, img_file in enumerate(img_files_temp):
            img  = skimage.io.imread(os.path.join('../Customized-DataLoader/data/train_img', img_file))

            img = skimage.transform.resize(img, output_shape=self.dim, mode='constant', preserve_range=True)

            X[i,:,:,:] = img
            index_of_label= int(self.img_files.index[self.img_files['Left-Fundus'] ==img_file][0])
            if len(self.img_files.loc[index_of_label][7:16].values)!= 8:
                continue
            y[:,] = self.img_files.loc[index_of_label][7:16].values
        return X, y

model = keras.applications.densenet.DenseNet121(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output1 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output2 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output3 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output4 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output5 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output6 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output7 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
output8 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(model.inputs,[output1,output2,output3,output4,output5, output6, output7, output8])
# print(model.summary())
model.compile(optimizers.rmsprop(lr = 0.0001, decay = 1e-6),
loss = ["binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy", "binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy","binary_crossentropy"],metrics = ["accuracy"])

def generator_wrapper(generator):
    for batch_x,batch_y in generator:
        yield (batch_x,[batch_y[:,i] for i in range(8)])



train_file = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test_file = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
train_generator = DataGenerator(csv_path = 'train.csv')
valid_generator = DataGenerator(csv_path = 'test.csv')
batch_size = 32
num_epochs = 1

STEP_SIZE_VALID =len(train_file)//batch_size
STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=len(test_file)//batch_size

model.fit_generator(generator=generator_wrapper(train_generator),
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,validation_data=generator_wrapper(valid_generator),
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                    epochs=5,verbose=1, workers =12,use_multiprocessing=True)
```

This trains without any errors, but the problem is the training is very slow, the GPU volatility is high for some time then goes to 0% and after some time shoots to 90%, can someone please help me fix this bottleneck ?

Any suggestions to keep the volatility to 100% will be very helpful, please let me know if any more info is needed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **In short:** you are not using the capabilities of `keras.utils.Sequence`, so although you specified 12 workers for multiprocessing, in fact you're only using 1 (you can check CPU usage to see how much core your code is using.

---

### How to improve the code?

- Instead of defining a generator wrapper that yields the samples (you can't make `yield` parallel, so this code will execute on ONE thread)

  ```python
  def generator_wrapper(generator):

    # THIS IS THE CULPRIT
    for batch_x,batch_y in generator:
      yield (batch_x,[batch_y[:,i] for i in range(8)])
  ...
  model.fit_generator(
          # THIS IS REALLY BAD
          generator=generator_wrapper(train_generator), ...)
  ```

  you should **pass the generator into `model.fit_generator` directly** as follows (please refer to [this tutorial](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly), this will make proper use of all of the `12` cores specified):

```python
    model.fit_generator(
            generator=train_generator, # other params
            workers=12, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

- **Don't use `skimage.io`, use `cv2` instead.** The reason is because `skimage.io` internally uses `Pillow`, which is reaaaaaaly sloooow comparing to `cv2`. You can find more info in [this benchmark in kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/vfdev5/pil-vs-opencv).
- Think about which step you DON'T really have to do in real-time. Do you HAVE to read the files again and again? Do you really NEED to resize the files again and again? I suggest you to **pack your files into HDF5** database. More info [here](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/). You can easily wrap it into `keras.utils.Sequence` class.